# Magento 1 Tare Weight

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, product-weight

Magento 1 doesn't allow you to enter tare weight (that I can find), so you have to include the weight of the box/packaging materials into the total item weight of each product. This works great for just 1 item purchase.

But this is causing a problem when a customer buys multiple items. The weight of the box/packaging materials (tare weight) gets added in multiple times. So for example if a customer buys 4 hats the weight of the box should be added in only 1 time. But because you have to add the box into the weight of each item it gets added 4 times.

Has anyone figured out how to add tare weight in Magento 1 so when a customer buys multiple items the weight is calculated correctly?